# Read-only file system Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, disk, external-hdd, disk-usage

I've switched from Windows10 to Ubuntu 20.04. After that a problem popped up with the 'D disk' or the 1Tb file system that is part of my computer hardware (I am pretty sure this is called HDD). I am unable to make any changes to the contents of this file system (remove files e.g.). It is read-only. Can anybody help resolve this issue?

Comment: Try and run the command `lsblk -f` and post the answer in your question. The problem might be related to the filesystem on your harddisk.

Comment: What does that command do exactly, please? Can you break it down

Comment: It lists block devices, including filesystem information. Either, your filesystem is mounted as read only, or contains a filesystem which can be read-only. So help us help you by providing more filesystem information.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone facing the same problem, you need to run these commands and you have to make sure about the path of your device using `df -h` where in my case, it is `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`

```
sudo -s
sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  
mount -n -o remount,rw /
```

Comment: Thanks! this is really help me !